# How to display xml tag dynamically the corresponding input array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, xml

My code is like this : http://pastebin.com/G74JY27f

```
<?php
$param = array('sex'=>'Mr.',
  'family_name'=>'Mourinho',
  'first_name'=>'Jose',
  'booking_phone'=>'123456',
  'booking_mobile'=>'123',
  'booking_email'=>'mourinho@gmail.com',
  'passenger_sex'=>array(
    'Sgl'=>array('Mr.'),
    'Dbl'=>array('Mr.','Mr.','Mr.','Mr.'),
  ),
  'passenger_family_name'=>array(
    'Sgl'=>array('Bale'),
    'Dbl'=>array('Hazard','Ronaldo','Messi','Beckham'),
  ),
  'passenger_first_name'=>array(
    'Sgl'=>array('Gareth'),
    'Dbl'=>array('Eden','Christiano','Lionel','David'),
  )
);

echo '<pre>';print_r($param);echo '</pre>';

$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

  <Request>

    <BookingRequest>                            

      <Name>".$param['first_name']."</Name>

      <Email>".$param['booking_email']."</Email>

      <Phone>".$param['booking_phone']."</Phone>

      <MPhone>".$param['booking_mobile']."</MPhone>

      <Passenger Room='SGL'>

        <PassSex>Mr</PassSex>

        <PassLocalNm>Gareth</PassLocalNm>

        <PassFirstNm> Gareth </PassFirstNm>

        <PassLastNm> Bale</PassLastNm>

      </Passenger>  

    </BookingRequest>

  </Request>";

$json = json_encode($xml);
$response_array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($response_array);
die();
?>
```

The result of `print_r($param)`, it is an array

The result of `print_r($response_array)`, it is xml

Name tag, email tag, phone tag and mphone tag in xml, that according to the data from the array

But the problem is the passenger tag, it still static

Seems using foreach, but I am still confused

The result there will be five passenger tag

So I want output like this http://pastebin.com/t380Aits

How to order the output looks like the above link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach loops to add the passenger tags to the xml variable.

You would do so by looping through one of the multidimensional parameters, and then looping through the values and using the keys of each array to get the related data from the other arrays.

See the below working code for an example of how to do this.

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

    <Request>

        <BookingRequest>                              

            <Name>".$param['first_name']."</Name> 

            <Email>".$param['booking_email']."</Email> 

            <Phone>".$param['booking_phone']."</Phone> 

            <MPhone>".$param['booking_mobile']."</MPhone>
";
// loop through one of the multi dimensional arrays
foreach ($param['passenger_sex'] as $type => $values)
{
    // loop through all values and add a Passenger record to $xml
    foreach ($values as $key => $val)
    {
        // use the $type array key, and the $key from the second loop to get the values
        $xml .= "
            <Passenger Room='".$type."'>

                <PassSex>".$param['passenger_sex'][$type][$key]."</PassSex>

                <PassLocalNm>".$param['passenger_first_name'][$type][$key]."</PassLocalNm>

                <PassFirstNm> ".$param['passenger_first_name'][$type][$key]." </PassFirstNm>

                <PassLastNm> ".$param['passenger_family_name'][$type][$key]."</PassLastNm>

            </Passenger>
";
    }
}
// add the closing tags to the xml string
$xml .= "
        </BookingRequest>

    </Request>";
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870